# Sphinx mysql " WHERE IN " for string colums

Tags: sphinx, where-in, sphinxql

Is there any way to perform the following query in sphinx index.

**SELECT * FROM search_index WHERE MATCH('sea*') AND object_type IN ('news', 'videos') LIMIT 0, 7**

This query doesnt  work and throw the following error

sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_STRING, expecting CONST_INT or '-' near ''news', 'videos')  LIMIT 0, 7  '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think very latest version of sphinx (released a few days ago) supports that, but not totally sure.

---

But you could also just use `field`s rather than `attribute`s, then can do it in the full-text query

```
SELECT * FROM search_index WHERE MATCH('sea* @object_type (news|videos)') LIMIT 0, 7
```